# What is the technical name for the birth and death dates that follow a person's name?

Tags: grammar, convention

There has been discussion here as to the proper way to indicate a [birth-death range for a person still alive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216570/birth-death-range-person-still-alive).

I would like to know what the the grammatical name of these dates.

For example, in the following sentence:

> Albert Einstein (1879–1955) invented the theory of relativity.

What is the technical name for the string "(1879–1955)" ?

Comment: Birth  and death dates are “personal data.”

Comment: I edited your question so it uses the more appropriate single en dash (–), as pointed out in the accepted answer of the question you linked to, rather than two hyphens (--).

Comment: I'm a LaTeX person. two hyphens are an en dash!

Comment: @vy32 Feel free to roll back the edit to suit your own style. (Although I would find it ironic to link to a question about this and then not use the styling that's recommended there.)

Comment: Generically, it's a **number range** and, more specifically, a **date range**. It's also (since you include the parentheses when talking about the string) **parenthetical information**. Grammatically, it might be a noun phrase, or, semantically, it could be an elided adjective phrase.

Comment: Is there anything in particular which makes you think there may be a word for that?

Comment: @TannerSwett, I thought that grammar people liked giving terms and names to everything!

Comment: The problem is that there are infinitely many things to name and only finitely much time to name them all. :D It seems unlikely that there's a single word or term for using a pair of parentheses to indicate a person's lifespan, just like there is (as far as I know) no single word or term for using a chainsaw to cut down a tree.

Answer (score 2):

In the art world, the artwork caption labels known as [tombstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_label) have what are formally known as "life dates." You can also find the term "life dates" applied descriptively in genealogy, biographical, encyclopedic, and other [archival contexts](https://narations.blogs.archives.gov/2019/03/28/whats-in-a-name/).

Here's an excerpt from the [Association of Art Editors style guide](https://www.artedit.org/style-guide.php#dates):

> Life dates: Give in full. Examples:
>
> 1908–1972
>       
>  Arminius (c. 17 B.C.–A.D. 21)
>       
>  385–331 B.C. (All digits are given for all B.C. dates.)
>
> Abbreviations may be used in text for life dates given in parentheses.
> Examples:
>
> born = b. (b. 1930) Note: this is
> preferable to the form (1930–)
>         died =
> d. (d. 1538)
>         about = c. or ca. (ca.
> 1489–d. 1538)
>         flourished = fl. (fl.
> 1503–30) (fl. 1530s) (fl. 16th century)
>       
>  date known but unverified = ? (1489?–d. 1538)
>     
>    active = act. (or spell out) (act. 16th century or active
> 1711–16)

[Rutgers Art Review's editorial style guide](https://rar.rutgers.edu/for-authors/style-guidelines/) calls them, quite literally, "parenthetical life dates":

> As an aid to the reader, please provide parenthetical life dates for
> historical figures, as well as publication dates for works discussed
> in the main text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a standardized technical term for it, but if I had to talk about the concept or if I had to propose easily understood terms, I'd go with **lifetime** or **life span**. After all, the terms work fine in general usage.

> Halley's comet was visible to the naked eye just once during Albert Einstein's lifetime, 1879–1955.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to put the term in the text. I want to know what the name of the term is. For example, If I am writing a book on style. To rewrite your sentence, I want to say "Albert Einstein (1879-1955) overlapped with one apperance of Halley's comet."

Comment: Yes, I got that. I was making a different point with the example sentence, that the the term is well understood in common parlance. It will work just as well in a technical context too, because 1879–1955 was Albert Einstein's lifetime.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the comment.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about the year, month or season then it should be: Born in.

> Example: I was born in 1980 (May, summer).

If you are talking about day of the week or a holiday then it should be Born on.

> Example: I was born on Monday (Christmas day).

And about death:

- Die in: Used to denote the situation at the time of death.

> Example: She died in peace.

- Die on: Used to denote the date of death.

> Example: He died on 5 July this year.

Comment: Thank you for the usage information. However, what is the technical name for the pair of years after a person's name?

Comment: @vy32 generally it is called lifespan