# Term for "place of death"

Tags: single-word-requests

Similar to how "birthplace" is a one-word term for "place of birth," I am looking for a one-word term for "location where someone died."

I am considering "terminus" but I'm not sure how widely-used that word is to refer to this concept.

Comment: *a one-word term for " "location where someone died."*. I don't recall ever seeing such a word. Contrary to expectations, English does not have a word for everything.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I am creating a list of facts about a person. Among the facts are "location of death," but that phrasing just sounds weird. I was hoping for a clean and widely-used single-word term like "birthplace" and figured it might just not be occurring to me, but now I see that it might be harder to come by than I had anticipated.

Comment: Well, I think *deathplace* is a highly unnatural word. Perhaps you could follow a style for biographical labels, incorporating place with time: *Mahatma Gandhi (d. 1948, New Delhi, India)*. See also my answer at [What is the technical name for the birth and death dates that follow a person's name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/540043/206976)

Comment: There's *deathbed*, but that might be a little too specific.  You're looking for something more on the geographical scale I assume?

Comment: Your title asks 'Term...' but your question body adds the (unreasonable) requirement 'one-word term ...'. That presumes that a common one-word term exists, which it doesn't; people don't use *"deathplace"*, I never heard it till today. *"place of death"* is the only common term. As for *terminus*, that's where buses or trains stop... unless it was an Agatha-Christie-worthy trip. ("Indiana Jones and the one-way fare to Fridge-Nuking")

Comment: "Terminus" is unsuitable, as it is already in common usage with less morbid connotations, as "railway terminus"

Comment: Is there a reason why "died" cannot be used? For example: **Born** in Vienna 1891.  **Died** 1961  in Salzburg, Austria.

Comment: I reckon @Mari-LouA has it right.  But 'deathplace', though unfamiliar, seems fine too if context requires it.  **1790**   W. Marshall *Rural Econ. Midland Counties II. Index sig. Gg6v/2*   Redmore, the death place of Richard III.  
**1830**   T. Moore *Byron II*. 778   His lost friend's melancholy deathplace, Missolonghi. 
**1908**   *Westm. Gaz. 16 Nov. 9/2*   Violating the precedents which prescribe the death-place of the rulers of China. **1992**   P. Baikie et al. *Absolutely 139*   Welcome to the birthplace and indeed, deathplace of Alexander Pope the famous poet from the Olden days.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you are looking for a single word you can use
***deathplace***. The term is not very common and appears to be mainly used in formal, literary contexts. Its most common alternative is [place of death](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deathplace%2C%20place%20of%20death&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeathplace%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplace%20of%20death%3B%2Cc0) .

***[Deathplace](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/deathplace)***:

> the place at which a person dies:
>
> - *Lincoln is buried in Illinois, but his deathplace was Washington, D.C.* - (Dictionary.com)

[deathplace:](https://www.lexico.com/definition/deathplace)

> The place where a person died or is going to die.
>
> Origin:
> Late 18th century; earliest use found in William Marshall (bap. 1745, d. 1818), agricultural writer and land agent. From death + place. - (Lexico.com)

Usage examples:

From: [A Radical American Vision](https://books.google.it/books?id=8ix1AAAAMAAJ&q=%22deathplace%22&dq=%22deathplace%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdrrnwjYXxAhX_g_0HHVCRD_w4ChDoATAEegQIBxAD) by Howard Zinn (2003)

> But it is also suggested that Boston is a good choice “ because the demand for justice , and the workings of injustice , have so often found expression in this home of the antislavery movement ,this birthplace of the American Revolution , ***this deathplace of Sacco and Vanzetti***.

From: [Byron - child of Passion, Fool of Fame](https://books.google.it/books?id=UeEKAQAAMAAJ&q=%22deathplace%22&dq=%22deathplace%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk6fPj4XxAhUCHuwKHebtD504ChDoATAGegQIChAD), by Benita Eisler (1999)

> In France, Delacroix' s stirring canvas *Greece Expiring on the Ruins of Missolonghi ( 1824 )*, while not based on a specific work by Byron, relied on the ***public' s knowledge of his deathplace*** to make the connection between the poet's sacrifice and the martyrdom of the Greek people.

Comment: I was considering this, but it sounds awkward to me. I personally never hear people using this term, but I suppose it is a legitimate word. I'll accept this if nobody else suggests an alternative. Upvoted for now.

Comment: @sion_corn - ‘place of death” is definitely  more common, but you asked for a single  word: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deathplace%2Cplace+of+death&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeathplace%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplace%20of%20death%3B%2Cc0 - I don’t think terminus is commonly used in that sense, probably metaphorically.

Comment: I ended up going with "Place of death". It conveys the meaning, and it is only 4 characters longer than "deathplace," so it suits my needs in terms of brevity.

Answer (score 14):

Croakation - location someone croaks

I know we hate neologisms here but as soon as I get enough points to post in meta trust that I will advocate daily for word equality, imagined and real

Comment: Spoken out loud, it seems like it would be easily confused with the homophone croquetion (i.e. location someone plays croquet)

Comment: I don't know if this answer is _useful_, but it's _funny_!

Comment: Nice Sniglet.  Remember those?

Comment: A vacation to Croatia?

Comment: A place of murder? (See if anyone gets that...)

Comment: @Rich  That would be "crowation."

Comment: Isn't croakation a holiday you take to practice croaking like a frog?

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing to this would, I think, be to pick a place where someone famously died and use it as a metaphor.  If someone died in exile, like Napoleon, you might write of “his Elba.”  One that’s a little more obscure: Martin Luther King, Jr. famously said, before his assassination, “I've looked over, and I've seen the promised land. I may not get there with you, but I want you to know tonight that we as a people will get to the promised land.”  You might extend that metaphor by talking of “his Nebo,” after the mountain where Moses saw the Promised Land and died (Deuteronomy 34).

I can’t really think of a location that serves as a metaphor for every person’s place of death, so this only really works if you find a metaphor that works for that individual, and if your readers know the story well enough to get it.

More likely, though, you want to rephrase your sentence. “Died at” is shorter to put in a geneological listing than “deathplace” (which I’ve also never heard before).

Comment: Resting-place is completely unrelated to place of death.

Comment: unless one is buried alive.

Comment: or drowns, or falls into a volcano, or dies on a space walk, is space a place, will you ever have a resting place?

Comment: @MikeW whether a corpse in space is "at rest" or not depends on your frame of reference. Relativity.

Comment: _Final resting place_ is a three word euphemism for _grave_ (but note it's also used for cremeted individuals). As you say, it's likely not the place of death.

Answer (score 1):

### Deathbed

This depends on context, given that it implies the presence of a bed. As such, it's not a good general term.

Don't get hung up on "birthplace". If you're looking for the generic terms for a set of biographical data, you can simply specify **born** and **died**. This gives you the freedom to add date and age at death:

- Born: [date] at [location]
- Died: [date] at [location] ([age])

Hope that helps!

Comment: Someone on his or her deathbed is expected to die of illness. It is possible for them to be on their deathbed and survive. (Example in the wild: “went from his deathbed to a full recovery”), someone who dies suddenly would never have a “deathbed,” and it wouldn’t be a good substitute for a phrase like, “Rome was his place of death.”

Comment: Granted, I originally suggested “resting-place,” which is just as inexact a match.

Answer (score -1):

A closely related word is '[final/last] resting place'. It's a euphemism for the place that someone is buried, in a grave or in a tomb.

Comment: While it's related, it's not what the question is asking for. Many people are interred at locations far from the place where they died.